# Please recommend a good, simple flatbed scanner with ocr software for public use at a non-profit

Tags: hardware

We are replacing our current, outdated scanners and are looking for something simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epson V10 is excellent document scanner with a really small footprint driver witch also support full automatic mode so you do not have to adjust dpi and doctype setting not even cropping. It recognize black and white print, artwork, color artwork and color photo. It is supported under linux on 32 bit version sorry no 64 bit driver yet. And the best thing is the way you open it. You can scan really thick books too because you can lie the spine on the cover.

Comment: discontinued I believe, but I went with the V30.  THanks

Answer (score 2):

Fujitsu Fi-6140 document management scanner

With Ubuntu 9.04

and latest latest sanebackend see www.sane-project.org
plus gscan2pdf.sourceforge.net and unpaper.berlios.de

Fantastic and non-techy person can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had good luck with HP peripherals, although I've not shopped for one lately.  Take a wander through their [scanner product pages](http://www.shopping.hp.com/scanner).

Answer (score 0):

We use an HP ScanJet 4890.  So far no issues.